# Account change for Partner Records

Tags: account, partner-portal

I’ll need to have all SFDC Channel Partner Account Records and corresponding Channel Contacts assigned to Matthew McLarty. My question is how can I identify the channel partner accounts from the regular accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partner created Account or Contact records can be identified using merge field `CreatedBy.UserType` field on User object.

`UserType` value is based on the User's license and partner users will have value as 'PowerPartner'. Please check [Salesforce docs](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) for various values of UserType field.

You can use [Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm) to evaluate the Account and Contact records for CreatedBy's UserType value and re-assign the record's owner.